# JSII ProcessBuilder cannot run program

Tags: aws-cdk

JsiiEngine createNewObject is throwing the below exception from ProcessBuilder calling start [here](https://github.com/aws/jsii/blob/main/packages/%40jsii/java-runtime/project/src/main/java/software/amazon/jsii/JsiiRuntime.java#L312). How to resolve this?

```
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory
    at software.amazon.jsii.JsiiRuntime.startRuntimeIfNeeded(JsiiRuntime.java:320) ~[jsii-runtime-1.95.0.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.jsii.JsiiRuntime.getClient(JsiiRuntime.java:422) ~[jsii-runtime-1.95.0.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.jsii.JsiiEngine.getClient(JsiiEngine.java:150) ~[jsii-runtime-1.95.0.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.jsii.JsiiEngine.loadModule(JsiiEngine.java:188) ~[jsii-runtime-1.95.0.jar:na]
    at software.amazon.jsii.JsiiEngine.createNewObject(JsiiEngine.java:608) ~[jsii-runtime-1.95.0.jar:na]
    at Mexc.Sdk.Spot.<init>(Spot.java:25) ~[Core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at mexctrader.config.MexcConfiguration.getSpotClient(MexcConfiguration.java:16) ~[classes/:na]
    at mexctrader.config.MexcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5aec6ba.CGLIB$getSpotClient$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at mexctrader.config.MexcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5aec6ba$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ad582dd6.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at mexctrader.config.MexcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5aec6ba.getSpotClient(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073) ~[na:na]
    at software.amazon.jsii.JsiiRuntime.startRuntimeIfNeeded(JsiiRuntime.java:312) ~[jsii-runtime-1.95.0.jar:na]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110) ~[na:na]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

CDK was not installed. Got resolved after installing aws-cdk using npm.